# C implementation of power function

Tags: c, recursion

I am a beginner trying to comprehend this innocent C function:
Given two numbers x and y, this function computes the power of x raised to y.

```
/* Function to calculate x raised to the power y */
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (y%2 == 0)
        return power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2); //what's happening here?
    else
        return x*power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
}
```

I am trying hard to trace the part where they multiply the return values from two functions. Suppose I pass in 4 and 3 as x and y, My function jumps to the second else part. and I return `4*(power(4,1)*power(4,1))`
as far as my understanding goes, the next call is to `4*power(4,0)*power(4*0)` and since y==0 returns 1, it should be 4*1*1 where I want 4*4*4. I am missing something here. What is this algorithm exactly doing?

The logic behind this function is to multiply x, y times. Can anyone please tell me how this simple division arithmetic (or divide and conquer) results in realizing the logic?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `3%2 == 1` and `3/2 == 1` so your function will jump to `4 * power(4,1) * power(4,1)`; `power(4,1)` will be converted to `4*power(4,0)*power(4,0)`, because `1%2 == 1` and `1/2 == 0`, so final result is `4 * 4*power(4,0)*power(4,0) * 4*power(4,0)*power(4,0)` which is `4*4*4`

Comment: @Lashane My question is how does power(4,1) return 4

Comment: @Tania I've updated comment

Comment: @Lashane I sorta seem to get it now.

Comment: the very first 'if' checks for a power of 0 and returns 1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The algorithm used is [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). It is divided into two parts, for a positive integer `n`

[image]

Therefore, the above function, for even exponent will return

```
power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
```

and for odd exponent will return

```
x*power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
```

It will calculate the power in order `log(n)` time.

For 2<sup>5</sup> it will be executed as:

- `5` is odd therefore `return 2*power(2, 5/2)*power(2, 5/2)` will be executed.
- `5/2 = 2`, an even therefore `return power(2, 2/2)*power(2, 2/2)` will be executed.
- `2/2 = 1` is odd therefore `return 2*power(2, 1/2)*power(2, 1/2)` will be executed.
- `1/2 = 0`, base condition therefore for both of `power(2, 1/2)`, `1` will be returned.

So,

- `return 2*power(2, 1/2)*power(2, 1/2)` will return `2*1*1 = 2` to its caller.
- `return power(2, 2/2)*power(2, 2/2)` will return `2*2 = 4` to its caller.
- `return 2*power(2, 5/2)*power(2, 5/2)` will return `2*4*4 = 32` to its caller.

A more efficient version would be

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;

    int t = power(x, y/2);  // power is called only once instead of twice.

    return y%2 ? x*t*t : t*t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the algorithm @haccks. Can you please explain why would we want to apply it here?

Comment: @Tania it's because it is a recursive function. The function itself does not calculate any powers, until the power has been halved until it is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @Tania; Added the explanation.

Comment: Cute but you need a halting condition for zero.  Fails for `pow(2,0)`

Comment: @Motti; Good catch :). A shorter version for you: `int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    if (y%2 == 0) 
         return power(x*x, y/2);
    else
         return x*power(x*x, y/2);
} ` :)

Comment: It almost makes more sense just to declare the function and `x` and `t` as `long`, since any type capable of promotion will be accepted. `y` is fine. You need something larger than `power (2, 32) - 1` as the exponent and you need another method and library to handle the results for anything other than the trivial case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin; Agreed, but actually I just explained how the algorithm works.

Comment: Agreed, it was more of a **tongue-in-cheek** suggestion for you `:p` (great answer by the way)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, the following does a power and demonstrates recursion in an easier to understand manner:

```
int power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;

    return x * power(x, y-1);
}
```

This shows a simple way to use recursion to handle a power calc.  The method you have will still roughly do what this does, but it's maximum stack depth will be much better (it will recurse less) because it divides the work up a bit better.

Not sure why you'd use either in the real world though.  Iteration would probably be far superior, or perhaps a logarithm - multiply exponent - antilog approach (which would handle franctional exponents as well).

In addition, this type of calculation is also prone to overflow integer values  really, really fast as well so please beware.

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of doing the divide-and-conquer recursion.

Comment: For sure, but as he said he was a beginner, I assumed he would want to see a "simple" recursion example.