How do I determine the distance between point (x1, y1) and point (x2, y2), and assign the result to pointsDistance?
Determine the distance between point (x1, y1) and point (x2, y2), and assign the result to pointsDistance. The calculation is:
Ex: For points (1.0, 2.0) and (1.0, 5.0), pointsDistance is 3.0.
enter image description here
pointsDistance = sqrt ((x2-x1) * 2.0 +(y2-y1) * 2.0);

Please add your code as text (not screenshots), so we can copy and run it ourselves. And say what is the specific problem with it you're having.

Post code as text instead of as image.

Also expected output and current output.

"pointsDistance = sqrt ((x2-x1) * 2.0 +(y2-y1) * 2.0);" No, that's not the right formula. Look closely at it.

C does not have an exponent operator inbuilt. You either need to use the pow function or just multiply twice since your exponent is 2. Also * is not the exponent operator. suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951002/c-implementation-of-power-function for detailed understanding of power function implementation. divide and conquer is a beautiful algorithm :)

Just use pointsDistance=hypot(x2-x1,y2-y1);. Function hypot() is in .

There should be an exponentiation of 2 (^), not a multiplication by 2 (*). There is no built-in exponentiation operator in C++, so you can do this if you need it in one line:
pointsDistance = sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));

Or so, but it may work slower:
pointsDistance = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2.0) + pow(y2 - y1, 2.0));

